# Quick method to evaluate MXD project for dashed line

Tags: arcobjects, export, illustrator

ArcMap export of a layout to Adobe Illustrator file converts all dashed-line symbology into dashes or dots that are not selectable as one object.

How can I use ArcObjects .NET to access symbol properties in an MXD to warn users.

Comment: which version of Ai are you with?

Answer (score 1):

To me (Illustrator 16.0.0) i select as below

[image: Ai]

If you are with Ai Version <=5 then you can try the 
[plugin](http://rj-graffix.com/software/plugins.html#SelectMenu)